PHP 8.2 FastCGI + IIS 10 recommended settings
We are currently using PHP with IIS (until we can get a Linux server)
I haven't found a single post on the internet that has some recommended settings, especially Max Instances and Instance MaxRequests (because I think these are the two most important for performance - unless there are more settings that I missed)
I only found questions where the answers simply copy the text from Microsoft website, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637364/how-do-i-configure-iis-10-and-fastcgi-for-high-concurrency
But no post has an actual information on recommended settings. For example - should the Max Instances be as the number of cores? And then what should be Instance MaxRequests? Is there a good ratio between this and Max Instances?
In my case, our server has 8 cores so I set Max Instances to 8, and Instance MaxRequests to an arbitrary value of 800, but maybe I can set it to better settings?

As rule of thumb: Max Instances should be set as high as possible (your server hardware is the limiting factor), but you need to regard the usage of your RAM, as each instance will need additional system memory. Instance MaxRequests should also be set as high as possible (your server hardware is the limiting factor), but you need to regard the usage of CPU time and also to a certain degree usage of filesystem and network bandwidth. PS those values are also experience values, you may set lower values first and increase values over time, it's possible to use overcommited values to a degree

thank you, so there is no correlation between Max Instances and the number of cores?

There is no direct correlation. You can run several instances at 1 CPU core, they will share the CPU time of that core. Usually this is not a problem. Your operating system kernel will also do a load balance between all CPU cores. The reason why those settings exist is more for operational safety than operational performance. Using too high values might make your server unusable for other tasks, in case PHP needs too much CPU time, too much memory. Such cases, are usually either caused by a programming bug (infinity loop), by some kind of DoS attack or your server hardware is just too slow.

Thank you, your explanation made it more clear
